# Spring boot No default constructor found on @SpringBootApplication class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wonder why the field injection works in the `@SpringBootApplication` class and the constructor injection does not.

My `ApplicationTypeBean` is working as expected but when I want to have a constructor injection of `CustomTypeService` I receive this exception:

```
Failed to instantiate [at.eurotours.ThirdPartyGlobalAndCustomTypesApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a56ce70]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: at.eurotours.ThirdPartyGlobalAndCustomTypesApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a56ce70.<init>()
```

**Is there any reason why it does not work at `@SpringBootApplication` class?**

---

My SpringBootApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ThirdPartyGlobalAndCustomTypesApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

@Autowired
ApplicationTypeBean applicationTypeBean;

private final CustomTypeService customTypeService;

@Autowired
public ThirdPartyGlobalAndCustomTypesApplication(CustomTypeService customTypeService) {
    this.customTypeService = customTypeService;
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(applicationTypeBean.getType());
    customTypeService.process();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ThirdPartyGlobalAndCustomTypesApplication.class, args);
}

public CustomTypeService getCustomTypeService() {
    return customTypeService;
}
```

My @Service class:

```
@Service
public class CustomTypeService {

    public void process(){
        System.out.println("CustomType");
    }
}
```

My @Component class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("application.type")
public class ApplicationTypeBean {

    private String type;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SpringBootApplication` is a meta annotation that:

```
// Other annotations
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public @interface SpringBootApplication { ... }
```

So baiscally, your `ThirdPartyGlobalAndCustomTypesApplication` is also a Spring `Configuration` class. As `Configuration`'s [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) states:

> @Configuration is meta-annotated with @Component, therefore
>   @Configuration classes are candidates for component scanning
>   (typically using Spring XML's  element) and
>   therefore may also take advantage of @Autowired/@Inject at the field
>   and method level (**but not at the constructor level**).

So you can't use constructor injection for `Configuration` classes. Apparently it's going to be fixed in 4.3 release, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35846123/1393484) and this [jira ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13471).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: The quote is the key. I was in the need to downgrade from 4.3. where this is doable.